# Are points given for leveling random or always the same?

Tags: dragon-fantasy

So, would Ogden (or whoever else) always have the same stats at level 15 each play through? Or would he sometimes have greater strength, but less defense or something? And more importantly, does he always get the same spells at the same level? I know it's the same order, but does the level he gains the spell vary? Or will he always get blastios at (14 I think?) the same level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well I decided to make another file to test this. The answer is that yes it is random, but he gets the same spells at set levels. Results:

guy 1)                           guy 2)

LVL: 19                          19

Strength: 35                     39

Agility: 37                      40

Intelligence: 35                 36

Vitality: 29                     24

Luck: 17                         13

Attack: 34                       36

Defense: 37                      35

Magic Defense: 8                 9

Hit: 84.34%                      85.10%

Evade: 9.34%                     10.10%

Equipment: Iron Sword, Iron Helmet, Iron Armor, Leather Shield  (same for both guys)

Spells: (same for both)

Healios, Blastios, Venomios, Antidotios, Silencios, Exitus, Slumbarios.